# Finding top N entries per group in Arango

Tags: aggregate, arangodb, aql

I'm trying to efficiently find the top entries by group in Arango (AQL).  I have a fairly standard object collection and an edge collection representing Departments and Employees in that department.

> Example purpose: Find the top 2 employees in each department by most years of experience.

### Sample Data:

"departments" is an object collection. Here are some entries:

| _id | name |
| --- | --- |
| departments/1 | engineering |
| departments/2 | sales |

"dept_emp_edges" is an edge collection connecting departments and employee objects by ids.

| _id | _from | _to | years_exp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dept_emp_edges/1 | departments/1 | employees/1 | 3 |
| dept_emp_edges/2 | departments/1 | employees/2 | 4 |
| dept_emp_edges/3 | departments/1 | employees/3 | 5 |
| dept_emp_edges/4 | departments/2 | employees/1 | 6 |

I would like to end up with the top 2 employees per department by most years experience:

| department | employee | years_exp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| departments/1 | employee/3 | 5 |
| departments/1 | employee/2 | 4 |
| departments/2 | employee/1 | 6 |

### Long Working Query

The following query works! But is a bit slow on larger tables and feels inefficient.

```
FOR dept IN departments
    LET top2earners = (
        FOR dep_emp_edge IN dept_emp_edges
            FILTER dep_emp_edge._from == dept._id
            SORT dep_emp_edge.years_exp DESC
            LIMIT 2
            RETURN {'department': dep_emp_edge._from,
                    'employee': dep_emp_edge._to,
                    'years_exp': dep_emp_edge.years_exp}
        )

    FOR row in top2earners
        return {'department': dep_emp_edge._from,
                'employee': dep_emp_edge._to,
                'years_exp': dep_emp_edge.years_exp}
```

I don't like this because there is 3 loops in here and feels rather inefficient.

### Short Query

However, I tried to write:

```
FOR dept IN departments
    FOR dep_emp_edge IN dept_emp_edges
        FILTER dep_emp_edge._from == dept._id
        SORT dep_emp_edge.years_exp DESC
        LIMIT 2
        RETURN {'department': dep_emp_edge._from,
                'employee': dep_emp_edge._to,
                'years_exp': dep_emp_edge.years_exp}
```

But this last query only outputs the final department top 2 results. Not all of the top 2 in each department.

My questions are: (1) why doesn't the second shorter query give all results? and (2) I'm quite new to Arango and ArangoQL, what other things can I do to make sure this is efficient?

Comment: Can you share the explain output for the first query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query is incorrect as written (`Query: AQL: collection or view not found: dep_emp_edge (while parsing)`) - as I could only guess what you mean, I ignore it for now.

Your smaller query limits the overall results to two - counter intuitively - as you are not grouping by department.

I suggest a slightly different approach: Use the edge collection as central source and group by _from, returning one document per department, containing an array of the two top resulting employees (should they exist), not one document per employee:

```
FOR edge IN dept_emp_edges
  SORT edge.years_exp DESC
  COLLECT dep = edge._from INTO deps
  LET emps = (
    FOR e in deps
       LIMIT 2
       RETURN ZIP(["employee", "years_exp"], [e.edge._to, e.edge.years_exp])
  )
  RETURN {"department": dep, employees: emps}
```

For your example database this returns:

```
[
  {
    "department": "departments/1",
    "employees": [
      {
        "employee": "employees/3",
        "years_exp": 5
      },
      {
        "employee": "employees/2",
        "years_exp": 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "department": "departments/2",
    "employees": [
      {
        "employee": "employees/1",
        "years_exp": 6
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If the query is too slow, an index on the `year_exp`-field of the `dept_emp_edges` collection could help (Explain suggests it would).